# Different style of long divison using polynom package

Tags: polynom, polynomials

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{polynom} 
\begin{document} 
\[
    \polylongdiv{x^3-5x^2+2x+8}{x-2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Hi,

The above code produces

[image]

while in teaching, we are more used to **SUBTRACTING** than **ADDING** instead,
so is there a tweak to make it into something like

[image]

The 0 at the end does not matter.

Also is there a way to make the bracket on the right-hand side of x-2 closer to the top divison line?